# Rust and OpenGL setup

Tags: opengl, rust

I'm trying to export my OpenGL game from C++ to Rust and achieve 2 things:
1. Print OpenGL error messages to console.
2. Autocompletion of GL functions and constants in my IDE (Visual Studio Code).

I simly generated OpenGL bindings with [gl_generator](https://crates.io/crates/gl_generator) crate and copied `bindings.rs` file to my cargo.

```rust
extern crate sdl2;
mod bindings;
use bindings as GL;

fn main() {
    let sdl = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let mut event_pump = sdl.event_pump().unwrap();

    let video_subsystem = sdl.video().unwrap();

    let gl_attr = video_subsystem.gl_attr();
    gl_attr.set_context_profile(sdl2::video::GLProfile::Core);
    gl_attr.set_context_version(4, 5);

    let window = video_subsystem.window("Window", 900, 700).opengl().resizable().build().unwrap();
    let _gl_context = window.gl_create_context().unwrap();

    let gl = GL::Gl::load_with(|s| video_subsystem.gl_get_proc_address(s) as *const std::os::raw::c_void);

    unsafe{ gl.Viewport(0, 0, 900, 700); }

    'main: loop { 

        unsafe {
            gl.UseProgram(42); // <- error (^ GL error triggered: 1281)
            gl.ClearColor(0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0 );
            gl.Clear(GL::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        window.gl_swap_window();

        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
                sdl2::event::Event::Quit {..} => { break 'main },
                _ => {},
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that `gl` variable, where all functions are stored, is not global and I'm not sure how to use it with different modules/functions.
The reason why all functions are inside `Gl` struct is because I used `DebugStructGenerator` in my build function. It prints not only errors but all OpenGL function calls (e.g., `[OpenGL] ClearColor(0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0)`). Would be great if it only printed error messages.

My `build.rs` file:

```rust
extern crate gl_generator;

use gl_generator::{Registry, Fallbacks, /*StructGenerator, GlobalGenerator,*/ DebugStructGenerator, Api, Profile};
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let mut file_gl = File::create(&Path::new(&out_dir).join("bindings.rs")).unwrap();
    let registry = Registry::new(Api::Gl, (4, 5), Profile::Core, Fallbacks::All, [ "GL_NV_command_list" ]);
    registry.write_bindings(DebugStructGenerator, &mut file_gl).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include the bindings.rs:

```
pub mod gl {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/gl_bindings.rs"));
}
```

Include this in your *main.rs* or *lib.rs*. Then you can include the gl functions from any of your modules just with (as gl is includes as pub module):

```
// anywhere in a module
use crate::gl;            // static gl with lot of constants e.g gl::ARRAY_BUFFER
use crate::gl::Gl;        // gl instance struct with gl: &Gl => gl.bindBuffer(...)
use crate::gl::types::*;  // include all gl types like GLuint, GLenum, ...
```

As we are in rust, you need to provide your gl instance to your functions as reference or whatever you want.

Maybe check [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/), which can be used as global variable:

```
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref gl: gl::Gl = create_opengl_context();
}
```

First access to gl will call the create context function. Repeated calls will use the created instance.

Maybe have a look at my game-gl library (graphics branch) at
https://github.com/Kaiser1989/game-gl or the example at https://github.com/Kaiser1989/rust-android-example. (Android and Windows openGL game loop framework)
.